# Webpack Production environment that is inside controller not working?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, html-framework-7

### controller.js

```
var MyApp = angular.module('index', []);
MyApp.controller('IndexPageController', [
 '$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$localStorage', 
 'urlservice','openurlservice', 'InitService',
 function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $filter, $localStorage,
           urlservice, openurlservice, InitService) {
   alert("test");
}]);
```

### app.js

```
angular.module('index', []);
angular.module('ini', []);
angular.module('student', []);
angular.module('myaccount', []);

MyApp.angular =angular.module('MyApp',
   ['ngRoute','ngStorage','index','ini','student','myaccount'])
.run(function ($rootScope) {
})
```

this is the code, we are using , when we are running in developer mode the alert pop ups, but the same code while running in production no alert is displayed!

Comment: It is not wise to define the `index` module twice. If the `controller.js` file is loaded before the `app.js` file, the controller will be deleted.

Comment: we are loading controller.js only after app.js is loaded.